# Javascript keyboard event keys aren't accurate with my keyboard layout

Tags: javascript, keyboard, key, keycode

here is my issue: 
I want to know which key got typed whenever I type something on a page and

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    console.log(event.key);
});
```

works fine but I recently found out issues with it. 
I will give an example related to the backtick character (`), but keep in mind that it doesn't affect only this character. 
I have an AZERTY keyboard, here is my layout : [image: Text] 
Whenever I press "Right-Alt + Key7", it should log the backtick character but logs "è". I found out that the on-screen azerty keyboard of windows has a different key, this one: [image: Text] there's no backtick 
 So I pretty much understand why it doesn't log backtick, my azerty layout isn't the windows' one or stuff like that. 
 But then my question is: 
 **Why does it prints backtick whenever I type on a textarea for example?** It is working everywhere excepts on keyevents. And most importantly how? **How can I, too, get the right keys everytime?**

I began looking for tricks to get the rights keys like putting a non-visible contenteditable div in front of the page to take its text... it could work, but you might understand why I don't want to go that path. **Is there any other tricks or solutions that are prettier?**

I hope I made myself understood, thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was using the "keydown" event and not the "keypress" one which works as intended, sorry for bothering and I hope people with the same issue will be able to find this!

Comment: The "keypress" event is deprecated though (source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event).


Is there a way to use "keydown" and still get the correct character?